# dplyr mutate_at but using any instead of all

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use `mutate_at(col_names,as.numeric)` but sometimes a column isn't included in the dataframe. For example the following works fine:

```
df <- data.frame('a'=c('1','2','3'),
           'b'=c('1','2','3'),
           'c'=c(1,2,3),
           'd'=c('1','2','3'))

col_names=c('a','b','d')

df |> mutate_at(col_names,as.numeric)
```

But if instead I swap out one of the col_names for something that isn't there, I get an error:

```
col_names=c('a','b','frog')

df |> mutate_at(col_names,as.numeric)

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `frog` doesn't exist.
```

Ultimately I think what I'm looking for is something like mutate_any().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mutate_at` has been deprecated, `across()` is now preferred which works with the `any_of()` and `all_of()` helper functions (and other select helpers).

```
df |> mutate(across(any_of(col_names), as.numeric))
```

See the `?across` help page for more options and examples.